# Why does the option to close question as off-topic as belonging to other SE site present only to some questions?

Tags: support

When a flag is raised for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422435/running-ubuntu-on-16gb-thumb-drive) to be closed as off-topic, there is an option to choose whether it belongs to other Stack Exchange sites.

[image: option present]

However, the same option is absent for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224173/wheres-the-best-place-to-begin-to-master-ubuntu/224178):

[image: option absent]

Is this a bug, or is this applicable option only to specific question?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, and I just tested.

Comment: Similar problem...

Comment: @ThomasW.: Do you get the options in both the above questions or you don't have an option in both those questions?

Comment: I am able to reproduce this. Or, I should say, was since one of the questions is now closed.

Comment: Here's another example which shows "migrate to Meta": [Github ask for Username & password after Configure ssh?](http://askubuntu.com/q/422999/176889)